# Inequality in a bounded real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove that for any bounded real sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ there exist two distinct natural numbers $u,v$ such that:
$$|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|\leq 1.$$

Comment: Any motivation/attempt?

Comment: Just an observation: If the statement is true, it is also true if you replace $1$ by any $C>0$.

Comment: IMO 1991, problem 6: for any $\alpha > 1$, there exist a bounded real sequence such that $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|^\alpha >1$. I strongly believe that for $\alpha=1$ this is not true anymore, but some reasoning about the limit points of the sequence (they must be infinite) and the application of the Erdos-Szekeres theorem did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: The 'what you have tried' meme misfires again!  Problem-statement-only question is a hard, $\geq$ olympiad level problem and not a trivial homework question.  I do think people should stop posting those automatic comments if they do not understand the problem well enough to know what the OP could/should have done before posting.  Yes, this means either thinking about the problem or declining to comment.

Comment: @zyx Perhaps, but I think people are responding more to two potential flaws about this post: 1. It is written in the imperative, and while some don't mind others do see this as a little bit rude. 2. Context helps people refine and improve their answers. Knowing the lines the OP has attempted and the source of the problem goes a long way to help people craft a better response. Maybe we can start replacing this "what you have tried" meme with something more specific.

Comment: @proximal, I think the suitability of imperative mathematics question varies according to location, culture, education system, and English proficiency. Ultimately it comes from the imperative style used by books, schools and competitions which are the main sources of problems.   Indeed a more specific, less automatic form of comment would be good but it should be where somebody *actually does want* that information (to attempt to answer the question, for example) instead of a ritual to enforce certain styles of posting.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the sequence $\{n\sqrt 2\}$ (braces denote the fractional part) or about Diophantine approximations of quadratic irrationals in general?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a counter-example using [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29)

Let $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ be the golden ration.
Since the inequality $|\phi - p/q| < 1/3q^2$ has finitely many solution for integers $p,q$,
let $N$ be an integer greater than all the $|p|$ occurring in those solutions.

Let $x_n = 3n\phi \pmod {3N}$

Suppose you find distinct integers $u$ and $v$ such that $|x_u - x_v||u-v| < 1$.
Then there are integers $p_u$ and $p_v$ such that $x_u = 3u\phi - 3Np_u$ and $x_v = 3v\phi - 3Np_v$. So $|3(u-v)\phi-3N(p_u-p_v)||u-v| < 1$, and $|\phi - N(p_u-p_v)/(u-v)| < 1/3(u-v)^2$. Hence $(N(p_u-p_v), u-v)$ is one of the finitely many solutions to the inequality above, hence $N > |N(p_u-p_v)|$. This implies $p_u = p_v$, and we get $|\phi| < 1/3(u-v)^2 \le 1/3 < \phi$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice counterexample. Actually, any quadratic irrational will work, there's nothing particularly special about the golden ratio. You can use Dirichlet's result that if $\alpha$ is a quadratic irrational then there is a $C > 0$ such that $\lvert\alpha-a/b\rvert > C/b^2$ for integers $a,b$.

Comment: Just noticed Fedja's comment to the question, which hints at the same idea.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther : thanks for that reference. Since transcendent numbers are out because their irrationality measure is greater than $2$, do you know if we know about the rest of the algebraic numbers ?

Comment: The numbers for which this argument works are precisely the *badly approximable* numbers. Equivalently they are the numbers whose continued fraction expansion has bounded coefficients (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Diophantine_approximation&oldid=556304832#Badly_approximable_numbers). This is an uncountable set, so includes many transcendental numbers.

Comment: Also, it is believed that all real algebraic numbers which are not rational or quadratic have unbounded continued fraction coefficients, so are not badly approximable. However, afaik, this has not been proved in any cases at all, so it is still open (but very unlikely) that all real algebraic irrationals are badly approximable. (I'm a bit unsure about that final statement though).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any solid proof, but I do have some evidence to suggest that the proposition might be false: a proof that if there are always such $u,v$ pairs, then they occur frequently in any sequence, and second, a computed example of a sequence that has no such $u,v$ pairs, yet appears to be bounded.

Take a bound $[a,b]$.
Consider $S_n$, the set of finite sequences such that $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|<1$ for some $u,v$. Then, $|x_u-x_v|=\frac{1}{|u-v|}-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, and so the set $$
[a,b]\times [a,b]\times\cdots\times(x_u-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x_u+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\times[a,b]\times\cdots\times[a,b]\times(x_v-\frac{\epsilon}{2},x_v+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\times[a,b]\times\cdots\times[a,b]
$$ is open in $[a,b]^n$ and is a subset of $S_n$, meaning that $S_n$ is open in $[a,b]^n$. It follows that, since $[0,b]$ is compact, by Tychonoff's theorem, $[a,b]^n$ is compact, and therefore, $\overline{S_n}$ is closed and thus compact. Let $C_n$ be the extension of $\overline{S_n}$ to $[a,b]^\omega$ by appending copies of $[a,b]$, so that by Tychonoff's Theorem, $C_n$ is compact. However, $\{C_n\}$ is a sequence of decreasing compact sets, whose intersection $\bigcap_{n\in N} C_n$ is nonempty if each $C_n$ is. An element of $\bigcap_{n\in N} C_n$ would be a sequence such that $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|\ge1$ for all $u,v$.

Thus, for a sequence bounded by $[a,b]$, if we can always find some finite sequence of length $n$ such that $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|\ge1$ for all $u,v$, we can find an infinite sequence violating the proposition. This means that, if the proposition is true, pairs $u,v$ will appear "commonly", in the sense that there is some $n$ at which all finite sequences of length $n$ must have a $u,v$ pair with $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|<1$, and so $u,v$ pairs will take up at least $\frac{2}{n}$ of the sequence.

A simple strategy of setting $x_0=0$ and $x_n$ to the minimum positive number such that $\{x_0,\cdots,x_n\}$ has $|x_u-x_v|\cdot|u-v|\ge1$ seems to work well, as demonstrated by the computer program below. The output of the program will have the bound on $\{x_n\}$ taper off to just above $2.5$ all the way into a sequence of length $250,000$, which seems to indicate that this naive sequence is bounded.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

#define EPS 0.0000000000000000002
#define NUM 250000
long double data[NUM];

static bool within(long double x, long double y, int n){
        long double test = (x-y)*n;
        return test >= (long double)(-1.0) && test <= (long double)(1.0);
}

main(){
        long double max = 0.0;
        int i;
        data[0] = 0.0;
        for(i=1; i<NUM; i++){
                long double test = ((long double)1.0)/i;
                int j;
                for(j=i-1; j>0; j--){
                        if(within(test,data[j],i-j)){
                                test = data[j]+((long double)1.0)/(i-j)+EPS;
                                j=i;
                        }
                }
                data[i] = test;
                if(test > max){
                        max = test;
                }
                if(i%100==0) printf("Got %d/%d -- max=%.15Lf\n",i,NUM,max);
        }
}
```